# web2py: Using db(...) in a module

Tags: python, web2py

My controller file is getting pretty huge so I've decided to start splitting it up to smaller methods and take the methods to multiple module files. First thing, is this clever? Is this the pythonic/web2py way?

Anyway, I create my first module file `my_module.py` in the Modules section (where there is `__init__.py` already). I define a method `my_method()` in the module. I import the module in my controller: `import my_module` and call the method in the controller: `my_module.my_method()`

controller:

```
import my_module

...

def my_page():
    ...
    my_module.my_method()
    ...
```

module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from gluon import *

def my_method():
    ...
    rows = db(db.my_table.my_field == x).select()
    ...
```

However, now it gives me error:

> File "/home/my_user/web2py/applications/my_app/controllers/default.py", line 568, in my_page
>
> my_module.my_method()
>
> File "applications/my_app/modules/my_module.py", line 10, in my_method
>
> rows = db(db.my_table.my_field == x).select()
>
> NameError: global name 'db' is not defined

I'm doing pretty basic db stuff and the method worked fine when it was defined in the controller itself. But why does the module work differently to the controller? Are there any other differences or caveats? Is using modules even worth it?

Comment: You should paste relevant part of code here, but it looks like you don't understand object oriented principles. Are you really speaking of functions or are you speaking about **methods**?

Comment: Right, I got the wrong terminology, and fixed it now. Sure, they are apples and oranges... but they mean quite the same thing and it doesn't matter here if I'm not talking about fruit business anyway. Also I had all relevant parts of the code listed but fixed it now so it's easier to see. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

web2py executes model, controller, and view files in a prepared environment (which is created fresh on each HTTP request). Objects defined in model files (including the `db` object) are added to this environment and therefore available globally within any controller or view. However, modules imported into controllers work the same as any other Python module -- they are not executed in the web2py environment, and therefore, objects in the web2py environment are not globally available within imported modules.

In this case, you have a couple options. First, you could simply pass the `db` object to the function as an argument:

In the module:

```
def my_method(db):
```

In the controller:

```
my_module.my_method(db)
```

Alternatively, you could add the `db` object to the `current` object and import `current` into the module (as documented [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Accessing-the-API-from-Python-modules)):

In a model:

```
from gluon import current
current.db = db
```

In your module:

```
from gluon import current

def my_method():
    db = current.db # Keep this inside the function, not at the top level of the module.
```

Finally, note that you can also access any objects in the web2py environment via the `current.globalenv` dictionary, so rather than explicitly adding `db` to `current`, you could simple access it via `current.globalenv['db']`.

Comment: Thank you! So it seems to be the easiest to use `current.globalenv` since that allows cut+pasting functions from controller to modules in the most straightforward way. No need to pass huge db objects all the time, or as you said, explicitly adding `db` to `current`. But this all makes me wonder, is using modules worthwhile? Or how do people split huge controller files in web2py? I have no plans on using the modules elsewhere, I just want to split for easier reading/developing.

Comment: First, the `db` object is not "huge," and there is no impact of passing it as an argument (Python does not make a copy of it). Using `current.globalenv`, you cannot simply cut/paste whole functions from a controller to a module -- you would still have to add references to `current.globalenv` in the moved function. In general, I would favor using explicit parameters -- makes the code more clear and concise, and makes testing easier. As for whether it is worth it, why not? You have the same issues when you import from any module into any other.